# get the value in the JTextfield after setText set the value into the Textfield JAVA

Tags: java

The situation is like this, first I set the text using the setText() function into the JTextField, then is it any way to retrieve the text that set into the TextField, I have already tried the getText() method, but the function get NOTHING from the TextField. Because my situation is complicated, so I must get the Text that set into the Textfield.

```
JTextField Jtf= new JTextField();
Jtf.setText("some value..");

String get = Jtf.getText();
```

I can't get the value that I set into the TextField, is there any solution for this? TQ.....

Comment: Your code is fine. Just checked at IDE, "some value.." is located inside `get` variable. You can check it `System.out.println(get);`

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: 1) Please follow Java naming conventions (variables must start with a lower case, while Classes with Capital letter). 2) do as @Andrej said, your value is actually on `get` variable.

Comment: honestly this should work, so just because you say that it doesn't, doesn't make this a good question that deserves a vote up!

Answer (score 0):

your code is right. text field should be instantiate in constructor check if not instantiate than do it, also check System.out.println(get), may you are doing wrong something.